# Solving the equation $2^{2x} - 2^x - 2 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$2^{2x}-2^x-2=0$$

I have tried to replace $2^x$ with $u$ and worked from there ended up with 2 solutions and then tried with $\log_2$, but I'm not sure whether it is correct. We know for sure that $x$ should equal to $1$. My question was about the interpretation to find. Can you suggest any?

Comment: the interpretation to find x*

Comment: By usual order of operations, you have written $2^2 x - 2^x - 2 =0$, but I suspect you mean $2^{2x} - \dots$, which would require "2^(2x)".

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Use $u=2^x> 0$ for real $x$

$$0=u^2-u-2=(u-2)(u+1)$$

Now $2^x=u=2^1$

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{2x}-2^x-2=(2^x-2)(2^x+1)=0$$

has the solutions

- $2^x=2$, or $x=\log_22=1$, allowed because the logarithm is a monotonic function
- $2^x=-1$, impossible.